# How do I prove that $\lim_{(x,y)→(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y)→(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0$$

I believe this is correct since I couldn't find a directional limit that won't validate this.
From what I know, I have to prove that

$$\forall\epsilon\gt 0, \exists\delta\gt 0$$
$$ \mbox{such that}$$
$$0 \lt \|(x,y)\| \lt \delta\Rightarrow \frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \lt \epsilon$$

I know that $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \|(x,y)\|$$

So I take $$\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \le \frac{2}{\|v\|}$$ and I kind of get stuck there. I greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: You have your $\epsilon$s and $\delta$s mixed up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
\lim_{(x,y)→(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=
\lim_{(x,y)→(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$

You surely know that
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1-\cos h}{h}=0
$$

Comment: Wow... i dont know how i missed that one. Seems like i fried my brain. Thanks a lot, you guys save me every time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another way
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)→(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos\left(x^2+y^2\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$
Using polar coordinates, we have
$$\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+} \frac{1-\cos\left(r^2\cos^2\phi+r^2\sin^2\phi\right)}{\sqrt{r^2\cos^2\phi+r^2\sin^2\phi}} $$
$$=\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+} \frac{1-\cos\left(r^2\left(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi\right)\right)}{\sqrt{r^2}\sqrt{\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi}} $$
$$=\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+} \frac{1-\cos\left(r^2\right)}{r} $$
$$=\left(\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+} r\right)\left(\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+} \frac{1-\cos\left(r^2\right)}{r^2} \right)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $$\cos(x^2+y^2) = 1 -\dfrac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2!}+\dfrac{(x^2+y^2)^4}{4!}-\cdots$$ we are led to the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** $$1-\cos x=2\sin^2\frac x2$$ and $$\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\to0\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{as}\,\,\,\,\,\,\theta\to 0.
$$